# How to include cookies with fetch request in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js, react-cookie

Consider the following code

```js
Index.getInitialProps = async function({req}) {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost/api/tiles");
  const json = await res.json();
}
```

Suppose the `/api/tiles` endpoint needs access to the `uid` cookie on the user.
Normally, one would do `{credentials: "include"}`.
But how do I do this in Next.js?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As you are using `React` (NextJS is built on ReactJS) you can use `react-cookie` to get and cookies that are stored in the system.

Install `react-cookie`

```sh
npm install react-cookie
```

If you are using Reactjs with version `>= 16.8.0` you can use React hooks.

```
const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(['cookie-name']);
```

You can set cookie with `setCookie(name, value, [options])` and get the cookies with `cookie.get(name, [options])`

So in your case the code should look like

```
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';
const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(['name']);

Index.getInitialProps = async functon({req}) {
  cookie = cookies.get(name)
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost/api/tiles", cookie);
  const json = await res.json();
}
```

Comment: Absolutely no reason you need to install an external library for this, let alone a react-specific library. This should not be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using over v13.4.0, there are 2 ways to include cookies for frontend fetching and backend fetching.

```
const res = await fetch('/url', {credentials: 'include'})
```

```
import {cookies} from 'next/headers';

const getCookie = async (name: string) => {
    return cookies().get(name)?.value ?? '';
}

const cookie = await getCookie('cookie-name');

const res = await fetch('/url', {
    headers: {
        Cookie: `cookie-name=${cookie};`
    }
});
```

Comment: Fyi for those not familiar with specific Next.js version numbers, this only works with the App router version of Next.js.

Comment: does the `credentials:'include'` method work? does this add the same cookies as the next/headers `cookies().getAll()` method returns?

Comment: Yes, right. Additionally the first way is for client side and the second way is for server side.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
const options = {
  method: "POST",
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Cookie": "access-token=YOUR-TOKEN;path=/;expires=Session" 
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({}),
  cache: "no-store",
};

fetch("YOUR-URL", options).then(response => response.json().then(data => console.log(data)));
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely do not need an external library to do this. Also `getInitialProps` has been deprecated, use `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps` instead.

On the frontend, setting `credentials: "include"` in the fetch will pass the cookies, but on the backend this will not forward the client's cookies. In order to do that on the server, you can retrieve the cookies via `context.req.headers.cookie` and explicitly pass this cookie in the `headers` object.

The following works:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { cookie } = context.req.headers;
  const res = await fetch(url,
    {
      credentials: "include",
      headers: { cookie },
    }
  );
  const data = await res.json();
  return {
    props: { data }
  }
}
```

(obviously you probably want to do some error handling on the fetch, but that's outside the scope of the question)